# Assignment Help - Multiple Activities passing Intent

Tags: android

Im trying to pass some information from my second Activity to the First Activity half of it is being sent and I can't seem to figure out why the other half isn't working. So for Example in the Second Activity once the user sees the total amount they have to pay. They have the option of selecting to pay by either "Cash" or "Credit Card" through the radio buttons. If by cash it goes back to the first Activity, showing the amount they have to pay. If they choose by credit card there's a 50% chance the transaction may not go through (bad network) and display an error message in the first Activity. I try to do this by using a random number generator from (0, 1) if rng is 0 then the transaction was successful, which is currently working. If rng is 1 the transaction isn't successful. This is what I currently need help with as its not showing the unsuccessful transaction at the moment.

I would like to thank everyone in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logic code, in SecondActivity class, you can change `credit()` method to

```
private void credit() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randnum = rand.nextInt( (1) + 1 );
    Intent intentResult = new Intent();
    String totalCost = "Total is: " + totalString + " inc. HST";
    if (randnum == 0) {
        intentResult.putExtra( "total", "Payment accepted.\n" + totalCost);
    } else {
        // Pass back total cost in case payment is not successful.
        intentResult.putExtra( "error", "Payment not accepted!\n" + totalCost); 
    }
    setResult( RESULT_OK, intentResult);
    finish();
    Toast.makeText( SecondActivity.this, "Random #: " + randnum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

and in MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String total = data.getStringExtra("total");
            String error = data.getStringExtra("error");

            if (total != null) {
                txtDisplay.setText(total);
            } else if (error != null) {
                txtDisplay.setText(error);
            } else {
                // Something goes wrong!!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I implemented the new credit() method in my SecondActivity.java class but the problem still persists. If the user chooses to pay by credit card. There's a 50% chance the transaction will fail. If it roles a 0, it passes and displays the information back to the first activity via a textView (txtDisplay) which currently works. However, if it roles a 1 it should go back to the same textView in Activity 1 (txtDisplay) letting the user know the transaction was failed. Currently if it roles a 1 the textView is still empty even with your method I implemented.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. This is exactly what I wanted. I appreciate you taking the time to look at my code. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear that. btw if my answer solved your problem, then you can mark it as answer, it will help me improving my answer in future =))

Answer (score 0):

Start activity B from A using startActivitywithResult() , finish B once work is done and send the result back to first activity using setResult() and then catch the result in onActivtyResult() in A.

Ref. link :
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the references. In my MainActivity class I did use StartActivityForResult() and passed information from Activity A to Activity B successfully (total cost of pizza). I also passed the total cost back from Activity B to Activity A. However if the user selects the radio button "Credit Card" and the random number generator happens to be 1. I can't pass back "Payment not accepted" from Activity B to Activity A. How would I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you try to debug ? What's happening in code flow during debugging?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging. I can't seem to resolve the issue.